# AssertJ Java: multiple conditions assertion

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, assertj

is it possible to write in Java AssertJ multi-conditions assertion which will pass if at least one of conditions met? (similar to OR operator)

I want something like this:

```
assertThat(listOfStrings)
           .satisfiesAnyOf(
                 a -> Assertions.assertThat(listItem).matches(someRegex),
                 // OR
                 b -> Assertions.assertThat(listItem).equals(someString)
            );
```

Assertion which will receive List of strings and will check each element of list against *Regex* and *equals another string*, all elements of list should satisfy at least one of conditions, and in that case - assertion should pass.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Tried a lot of options but none of them works perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked allOf / anyOf?

Comment: Yes, I've tried those.

Comment: And why don't they suit your purpose? can you show it?

Comment: It was complaining that I need to use "Predicate<? super String>" instead of just Regex (String). But from Stefano Riffaldi answer I learned eventually how to write those Predicates. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we are. you can fit `contains` and `matchesRegex` methods in variables, as you like !

```
package org.example.test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class MultipleConditionsTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Given
        String someString = "", regex = "";
        // When
        ArrayList<String> actual = new ArrayList<>();
        // Then
        assertThat(actual)
                .anyMatch(contains(someString).or(matchesRegex(regex)));
    }

    private static Predicate<? super String> matchesRegex(String regex) {
        return string ->Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string).matches();

    }

    private static Predicate<String> contains(String someString) {
        return string -> string.equalsIgnoreCase(someString);
    }
}
```

that you can combine as you wish, like this

```
@Test
public void containsOrMatchesRegexTest() {
    // Given
    // When
    List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList("banana", "apple", "orange");
    // Then
    assertThat(fruits)
            .as("At least one element should contain 'raspberry' or match the regex 'a.+?'")
            .anyMatch(contains("raspberry").or(matchesRegex("a.+?")))
            .as("At least one element should contain 'banana' or match the regex 'p.+?'")
            .anyMatch(contains("banana").or(matchesRegex("p.+?")))
            .as("No element should contain 'blueberry' or match the regex '.+?c.+?'")
            .noneMatch(contains("blueberry").or(matchesRegex(".+?c.+?")))
    ;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know how to write those Predicates. Thanks  a lot for showing how to write them correctly!

Comment: Perhaps you know how to add custom error message if assertion failed, so instead of "Expecting all elements of <List> to match given predicate but this element did not:" To show something more informative, is it only option to use ".as("custom message")" ?

Comment: afaik, yes; `as` method with appropriate message before condition

Comment: Actually, just found out that same result can be achieved with:
`.allMatch(s -> s.matches(someRegex) || s.equals(someString));`

Comment: in that way, each items have to match or be equals. requirements wasn't `assertion which will pass if at least one of conditions met` ?

Comment: Yes, but that what this does as well, all of List elements should match at least one of conditions, and there is `||` between conditions.  TYSM for help.